# How does coreutil's date manage to get such weird results?

Tags: date, coreutils

I was playing around with `date` to try to convert expressions such as "2 hours" to a number of seconds like 7200. I thought I could perform this with invocations such as:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 + 2 hours" +"%s"
```

Yet, I noticed extremely strange results while so doing. (My `/etc/timezone` contains "Europe/Paris", hence the use of `TZ` to force UTC times.)

```
omega:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00" +"%s"             
0
omega:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 + 0 minutes" +"%s"
60
omega:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 + -1 minutes" +"%s" 
3660
omega:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 + 1 minutes" +"%s" 
-3540
```

The first result is reasonable enough, but I'm really totally puzzled about how `date` might have come up with the three last results. Does anyone understand the logic between those results?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's taking your `+ x` as a time-zone specifier (e.g., consider `2013-04-25 19:52:36 +4` is a valid timestamp, in in a time zone 4 hours ahead of UTC).

It's then seeing the word 'minutes', and treating it as a synonym of minute, so giving you one minute later.

If you put in an explicit timezone specifier, it works:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" +"%s"   
0
anthony@Zia:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC + 0 minutes" +"%s"
0
anthony@Zia:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC + -1 minutes" +"%s" 
-60
anthony@Zia:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC + 1 minutes" +"%s" 
60
```

Note the `UTC` after the seconds field. You can also put in a second `+0`:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ TZ=utc date -d "1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0 + -1 minutes" +"%s"
-60
```

... but at least personally, that's much harder to read.

Or you can put a `Z` after the seconds, etc. You don't actually need the `TZ` environment variable to be set to UTC in the above examples.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. You can also write it `date -d '1970-1-1 0:0:0 1 minute'` and `date -d '1970-1-1 0:0:0 1 minute ago'`

Comment: Thanks for finding this out! Do you know any shorter way to obtain the number of seconds of a duration like "2 days" with `date`? (e.g., an abbreviation for the epoch)

Comment: @a3nm Suggest you ask a question on that. Durations are either trivial (1 day=86,400 seconds) or complicated (how long is one month? Was there a leap second?)